# AWS GP2 Charges

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need some help in understanding AWS charges.

Basically I am running some r4.large spot instances. However, from the cost explorer I notice the GP2 cost is nearly as much as the EC2 cost. I am provisioning them with 15GB of GP2, which is supposedly the cheapest, but it's a bit disappointing when the cost summary that compares them to on-demand shows a price but then that doesn't factor in gp2. Any advice on how I can reduce this? I don't care about HDD performance especially.

[image]

Comment: Go to EBS from EC2 tab and check how many gp2 or GB is there.

Comment: How much disk space are you allocating?  The graph looks like about $40/day... which is roughly 12 TB of gp2 depending on region.